# rip off a number out of a fraction

Tags: c

I am working on a project and I have an idea on how to start. Basically this is how the program runs:

```
$ ./rulerbuddy 2.25
2.25 is exactly 2 1/4
```

So, I kind of have the idea that I need first to rip off the whole number which in this case is '2' then start manipulating the fraction to get the result. My question is how can I rip off that whole number from the decimal fraction? Any ideas, steps, guide is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `floor` rounds down to the nearest integer, that should get you started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Take out the whole number and consider only the decimal part (do a `sscanf(input, "%d.%d", &intPart, &fracPart)` to take them apart).
2. Count the digits after the decimal point; your starting fraction is digits/10^number of digits, i.e. in your case 25/100;
3. Now you can simplify it finding the greatest common divisor (e.g. with [Euclid algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm)) and dividing both terms by it.

Quick example of how this can be implemented:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct Fraction
{
    int n;
    unsigned int d;
};

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if(b==0)
        return a;
    else
        return gcd(b, a-b*(a/b));
}

void simplify(struct Fraction * f)
{
    int divisor=gcd(f->n, f->d);
    f->n/=divisor;
    f->d/=divisor;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int intPart;
    unsigned int fracPart;
    struct Fraction f;
    if(argc<2)
    {
        puts("Not enough arguments.");
        return 1;
    }
    if(sscanf(argv[1], "%d.%u", &intPart, &fracPart)!=2)
    {
        puts("Invalid input.");
        return 2;
    }
    f.n=fracPart;
    f.d=fracPart!=0?(int)pow(10., floor(log10(fracPart)+1)):1;
    simplify(&f);
    printf("%s is exactly: %d %d/%u\n", argv[1], intPart, f.n, f.d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice example of how this program can be implemented. Thank you very much Mr. Matteo Italia

Answer (score 2):

```
if(num < 0)
    num = num * (-1);

then
Just type cast the number explicitly to `int`
```

Comment: that breaks when you have a negative number

Comment: not necessarily a wrong answer as OP didn't really specify if he needed to maintain negative numbers or just wanted the whole numbers. just thought i would point it out

Comment: @scrappedcola: I have one question. I just wrote a small snippet to test type casting negative floats and it didn't break as you pointed it out. Could you elaborate a bit on it?

Comment: This will be of a great help. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard library function **[floor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/floor/)**

```
#include <math.h>

int WholeNumber(double number)
{
    return (int)floor(number);
}

int main(void)
{
    int N;
    N = WholeNumber(2.25);

    printf("The Whole part is %d\n", N); // this will print 2
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to acquire the number as a floating point value, since he wants to transform it to exact fractions, and I doubt that 0.1 would give any satisfactory result when working with FP values...

Answer (score 1):

Try a regex

http://rubular.com/r/KkE34B4ODQ

I've set that up to work for your example, you may need to alter it based on what your program provides for whole numbers (ie.e 2 0/1) or whatever.

The first group is the whole
second is numerator
third is denominator

Comment: I wouldn't use regexes in a C program (=dependency on an external library) where a plain `sscanf` would suffice.

Comment: Good to know this, appreciate your help.